# How to show day of the week + format Date

Tags: android, date, format

```
Calendar.getInstance();

mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
mDateButton.setText(DaySet(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)+" "+DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(getActivity()).format(mCrime.getDate()));
mDateButton.setEnabled(false);



public String DaySet(int day){
        String mBuf="";
        switch (day){
        case 1: mBuf = "Sunday";
        break;

        case 2: mBuf = "Monday";
        break;

        case 3: mBuf = "Tuesday";
        break;

        case 4: mBuf = "Wensday";
        break;

        case 5: mBuf = "Thursday";
        break;

        case 6: mBuf = "Friday";
        break;

        case 7: mBuf = "Saturday";
        break;
        }

        return mBuf;
}
```

I need to show a date on the button that will look like "Tuesday, Feb 20 2014". So the second part of this date works, but first -doesn't. Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK shows me wrong constant. Probably you know better methods?

Comment: visit http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-get-current-date-month-year-dayoweek-dayofmonth-java-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will format calendar object to "Thursday, Feb 20 2014"

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("cccc, MMM dd yyyy");
String formatDate = format.format(cal.getTime());
```

See [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) at the official Android docs for more information.